# CSS3 odd and even only visible rows

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to stripe the colours of alternating elements. But I want the row colors to alternate only the visible rows. If you have a look at the below here is my attempt at trying to get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/kuwFp/3/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:not(.hide):nth-child(odd)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
p:not(.hide):nth-child(even)
{
background:#0000ff;
}
.hide { display:none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="hide">The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS. You'll have to resort to JavaScript.

Comment: It's possible if you can change the element type for hidden text, to let's say ..span

Comment: @one I tried taking a leaf from your book and tried this but it didn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/kuwFp/15/

Comment: No, I meant [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/PZuNC/). `nth-of-type` will count elements of the same type only...

Comment: @OneTrickPony Problem with this is in my case they all start off as divs and I would need to change them to spans on hide. This isn't a straight forward dom change.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this with pure CSS because the `:nth-child` selector is calculated with respect to the element and `:not` does not filter element position in the DOM.  You need to use JavaScript for a fully flexible solution.

It's still possible for you to do this *inflexibly* by making elements after `.hide` with `:nth-child` alternate the color they should be:

```
.hide + p:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #0000ff;    
}
```

You can continue to add similar rules for more and more combinations of sibling `.hide` and `p`, but this is very inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to hide a row with different tag, not class. In my example I use "del" tag to hide.

```css
.list div:nth-of-type(odd) { background: ghostwhite; }
.list del { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <del>4</del>
  <div>5</div>
  <del>6</del>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure this conforms to standards, but it sure is neat.

Comment: @GregSchmit, please share the "standards" you refer too. Thank you.

Comment: The standards would be HTML5 (or HTML 5.2), the current HTML standard from W3 or the WHATWG living standard. It does conform to standards after looking it up (hence the "not sure" part of my statement). I wasn't sure if `<del>` tags could be under `<div>`'s like that, as I've always used them under `<p>` tags. It's legal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code that hides and shows the elements, you could add another auxiliary hidden element right after each original hidden one, so the parity will be preserved for the css selector. Also, remove each following hidden auxiliary element when the original one is shown up again.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: now we can use the [`:nth-child(nth of selector)` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax), which, according to MDN, should be supported by most “evergreen” browsers (CR 111, FF 113, Safari 9).

```css
.list div:nth-child(odd of :not([hidden])) { background: ghostwhite; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div hidden>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div hidden>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div hidden>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```