# Change Table TR background color of every 2nd TR but ignore if display is none in CCS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this css code to change every odd/even tr bg color

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #b2b2b2;}
tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:black;}
```

But i am filtering table data and based on conditions some TR will be hidden.
so if `style="display: none;"` then apply odd/even rules only for visible TR only.
Otherwise it look like attached image

[image]

Comment: `nth-child` does not care about `display:none`, these elements still count as children. You need a different solution that takes the hidden state of the table rows into account, likely dynamically (so, JavaScript.)

Comment: Btw, did you try and research this before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057925/select-odd-even-child-excluding-the-hidden-child, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059388/css3-odd-and-even-only-visible-rows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432967/css-how-to-skip-hidden-child-in-nth-childodd-and-nth-childeven … anything but a new question.

Comment: Javascript is the way. You will have to add and remove classes based on the index of the visible TRs.

Comment: can you add a class like "hidden" and add the display: none via that class instead of adding the display: none?
If it is possible then I think you can use the hidden class in your selector to do this

Comment: @ZsoltBalogh no, you can not, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Answer (score 0):

Just add to tr class "disabled" {display: none;}

And add to your css:

tbody tr:nth-child(even):not(.disabled){background-color:black;}

Comment: No, it _does not_ work like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector